# Mixing Gases for laser

Tags: laser, experimental-technique, gas

Hello stack exchange community! I finally found a way to ionize air for less than $200! 1 small problem is mixing gases is coming out to be very difficult and i dont know if this is the right place to ask but here we go. What is my best way of mixing gases like co2, air, and helium = 1:1:6. What is the best way of mixing these gases? There is a russian i am talking to about my laser and he said he uses a car tire to mix stuff but thats not a very clean way of doing things. Whats the best way to mix these gases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really isn't the correct forum. Engineering would better address your question, but here's my thoughts.

If accuracy in mix is critical then your best approach is to use flow feedback controllers with mass flow meters that all mix into your chamber or manifold.

But it sounds like you are trying to keep the price low so then using an open loop approach, inexpensive pressure regulators and orifice plates for each gas. You can calculate the required diameter given upstream/downstream pressure. Best to keep the flow sonic (critical) so that mass flow rates are not so much affected by downstream pressure fluctuations.

Comment: Cheap is my way to go! I will give this a shot and let you know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hey everyone trying to mix gases! if the last answer was a little confsing to new comers heres a good idea that i was suggested. use a ballon and inflate it with your gases one at a time, each time stopping to see the volume inside the balloon by doing V = (4/3) * Pi * R^3. this is not so accurate but for the laser im building accuracy is not a huge requirement.